# Parse/Android. Getting User Associated with Object

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have an Android app that stores company names and those associated with the companies, using Parse.

I am able to get a column created called ownedby that stores the userID.

Now, I want to store information in the company column where the userID in ownedby equals the current user.  Here is the query I am using:

```
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("midwifefirm");

        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> midwives, ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(e==null) {

                    for (ParseObject midwifefirm : midwives) {
                        String midwiferelation;
                        ParseUser currentUser;
                        String userID;


                        midwiferelation = midwifefirm.getString("ownedby");
                        currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
                        userID = currentUser.getObjectId();

                        if (midwiferelation.equals(userID)) {

                            midwifefirm.put("yearsinpractice", yearsexperience);
                            midwifefirm.put("practicename", midwifefirmname);
                            midwifefirm.put("education", education);



                        }

                    }

                }
            else{
                Log.d("notretreive", "Error: " + e.getMessage());

                }




                                 }
                               });
```

This would seem to work; but in the backend, no data is stored, so I guess my "if statement" never works.

Is there anything obvious I am doing wrong?  This is for a thesis project, so I can attempt to fake things a bit for the demo, but would like to learn how to do it right.

Thanks so much

Michael

Comment: I think I might have spotted the problem.. 'ownedby' is a pointer, right?

Comment: @cYrixmorten yes it is

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I got the code below completely right. But the issue you have lies in the fact that `ownedBy` is a (as I understand) pointer to a User.

When you then try do `midwifefirm.getString("ownedby")`, you are not getting the objectId as you expect, instead you get something like `{'type':'__pointer', 'class' : '_User', 'objectId' : 'xxx'}` (I do not remember the notation but hope you get the idea; the literal pointer string value).

Knowing this it is not odd that an objectId `xxx` String never can equal `midwifefirm.getString("ownedby")`.

Instead of `getString`, you can call `getParseUser`, which will return an empty `ParseUser` with the correct objectId, recall that the pointer only has the minimal information needed to retrieve the object it points to.

You should now be able to make a direct comparison between your current `ParseUser` and the pointer `ParserUser`. The fact that the latter is empty should not matter as it only needs the objectId to perform the comparison.

Try this:

```
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("midwifefirm");

        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> midwives, ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(e==null) {

                    for (ParseObject midwifefirm : midwives) {
                        ParseUser midwiferelation;
                        ParseUser currentUser;



                        midwiferelation = midwifefirm.getParseUser("ownedby");
                        currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();


                        if (midwiferelation.equals(currentUser)) {

                            midwifefirm.put("yearsinpractice", yearsexperience);
                            midwifefirm.put("practicename", midwifefirmname);
                            midwifefirm.put("education", education);



                        }

                    }

                }
            else{
                Log.d("notretreive", "Error: " + e.getMessage());

                }




                                 }
                               });
```